# Sync the clock on Windows 7 to the time server more frequently

Tags: windows-7, sync, date-time, ntp, clock

On Windows 7, is the way to sync the clock to the time server more frequently still [the same as before](https://superuser.com/questions/136315/how-to-increase-frequency-of-time-server-synchronisations) [(by regedit)?](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/dealing-with-windows-vista-time-sync-problems/)

Are there other ways such as by using the control panel or system tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the same. It hasn't changed since Windows XP.

To change the delay, simply edit the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\w32time\TimeProviders\NtpClient
```

The value there is the number of **seconds** between updates.

Comment: I found that it was W32time ("W" instead of "w")... shouldn't matter since it seems case insensitive.

Comment: Windows is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

[Atomic Clock Sync](http://www.worldtimeserver.com/atomic-clock/) works well for me. But it is not yet officially supported on Windows 7 from what the notes say. But it works for Windows Vista, so it could still work.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7, the registry key is modified to:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\w32time\Config\UpdateInterval

Answer (score 0):

I like the method of using the standard windows task scheduler to set up a job that syncs more frequently.  What I like about this is that it works well and I don't have to mess with the registry.

See http://www.pretentiousname.com/timesync/ for a great write up on this.

The gist is:

Setup a task (run `taskschd.msc` from cmd line) to run at the frequency you desire.

You'll add two actions to the task running as `LOCAL SERVICE` user running with highest privileges.

## 1

program/script: `%windir%\system32\sc.exe`

arguments: `start w32time task_started`

## 2

program/script: `%windir%\system32\w32tm.exe`

arguments: `/resync`

Under settings make sure to check `Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed.`