# How to increase frequency of time server synchronizations?

Tags: windows-xp, sync, ntp

I have a  that PC (Windows XP SP3) keeps losing time whereby it ends up being about 5 mins slow per day from all the other PCs and clocks about the place.

**Is there a way to increase frequency of time server synchronisations** to keep this in check? Or better yet, a reason for this issue, perhaps some recent windows update has this side effect I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust it in Registry.

- start registry editor (regedit will do fine)
- go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpClient
- edit value SpecialPollInterval.

SpecialPollInterval is defined in seconds. If you wish e.g. 1 hour just write 3600. You can calculate rest from here.  Default is 604800 (7 days).

Comment: Yep that'll do it! Didn't seem to take effect until I changed the provider, but good enough. Thanks.

Comment: It's recommended to not set this property below 14400 (4 hours) to avoid getting banned from the time servers.